# Prevent certain iPhone apps from generating notifications unless they are open

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Most iPhone apps behave as expected while they are open, which is great.

However, some create spam notifications while they are closed, which is not.

Preventing all notifications from this class of app is easy, but usually their notifications are useful, especially while they are open in the background. Is it possible to restrict some Apps' notifications such that the app must be open (similar to how location querying may be restricted,) rather than preventing all notifications?

iOS 13.5.1.

Comment: have you tried experimenting with notification style ? banner/ show on lock screen/ etc

Comment: Yes - those are very easy to set, but do not adjust depending on if an app is open or closed!